# chdir in perl using two strings: chdir "/home/$dir1/$dir2"

Tags: perl, directory, chdir

I have two strings: `$dir1` and `$dir2`. I want to use `chdir` as shown below:

```
chdir "/home/$dir1/$dir2";
```

when I try this it doesn't change the directory. I checked the current working directory same as before

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: you can check your "current working directory" using `cwd` from [Cwd](https://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) module

Comment: If you actually tried that and it didn't work, I bet you have a newline at the end of one of your variables.

Comment: Please show us more of your code. How are you testing that the `chdir` is successful?

Comment: Are you aware that a process cannot change the directory of its parent process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically I write that as:

```
use v5.10;
use File::Spec::Functions;

my $dir = catfile( '/home', $dir1, $dir2 );
die "Dir <$dir> isn't a directory or doesn't exist" unless -e -d $dir;
chdir $dir or die "Could not change to <$dir>: $!";
```

Whenever you do something with the system, check the results to ensure it happened.

And, curiously, I didn't realize that Pearson's sample chapter of my book [Effective Perl Programming](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com) is [the one that covers stacked file test operators](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1582932).